# Version Lens showing latest recommendations that are below current versions

Tags: vscode-extensions, pubspec

I use Version Lens in github but today it started showing me versions that are well below the latest available versions. Does anyone know how to fix this?

This is for a Flutter project on flutter 3.10 and Dart 3.0.6

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling Version Lens, restarting my machine, and updating VS Code but nothing solved the problem.

Comment: I have the same problem ... does anyone know the solution?

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed now in v1.5.1 and respectively in v1.5.2 which is the current version.

Have a nice day! :-)